# How to do restful ajax routes to methods in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, restful-architecture

So I have a route that looks like this:

```
Route::any('some/page', ['as' => 'some-page', 'uses' => 'SomePageController@index']);
```

However, I also have ajax calls at the same URL (using a request parameter called *ajax* like: `some/page/?ajax=my_action`) that I want to hit methods on my controller:

```
index                   already routes:   'SomePageController@index'
ajax = my_action        needs to route:   'SomePageController@ajaxMyAction'
ajax = my_other_action  needs to route:   'SomePageController@ajaxMyOtherAction'
ajax = blah_blah        needs to route:   'SomePageController@ajaxBlahBlah
...
```

What's the elegant solution to setting this up in my *routes.php* file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After inspection of Laravel's Http Request and Route classes, I found the [route()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html#method_route) and [setAction()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_setAction) methods could be useful.

So I created a middleware to handle this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class Ajax {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Looks for the value of request parameter called "ajax"
        // to determine controller's method call
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $routeAction = $request->route()->getAction();
            $ajaxValue = studly_case($request->input("ajax"));
            $routeAction['uses'] = str_replace("@index", "@ajax".$ajaxValue, $routeAction['uses']);
            $routeAction['controller'] = str_replace("@index", "@ajax".$ajaxValue, $routeAction['controller']);
            $request->route()->setAction($routeAction);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Now my route looks like:

```
Route::any('some/page/', ['as' => 'some-page', 'middleware'=>'ajax', 'uses' => 'SomePageController@index']);
```

And correctly hits my controller methods (without disturbing Laravel's normal flow):

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SomePageController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return view('some.page.index');
    }

    public function ajaxMyAction(Requests\SomeFormRequest $request){
        die('Do my action here!');
    }

    public function ajaxMyOtherAction(Requests\SomeFormRequest $request){
        die('Do my other action here!');
    }
    ...
```

I think this is a fairly clean solution.

Comment: The idea behind this technique still holds up to this day, although I now prefer to say `'SomePageController@indexOrAjax'` because `indexOrAjax` is even more explicit.

Comment: i don't understand the idea behind "@indexOrAjax". Whats the difference?

Comment: It just gives a new developer the better clue in the routes file that the controller index method or a controller ajax method will be called.

Comment: Understood. I liked your approach, using middlewares. But after i read the discussion at https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1280, i started to arg what will be the best, stay using middlewares or use the controller callMethod or BeforeFilter approachs. Did you have any thoughts about those?

Comment: Actually I've moved away from this type of architecture now, so I haven't had a look at it since earlier this year. I now look at backends as APIs (where you don't return views, but more like view models in JSON). In the Java Spring framework, for example, you don't have a routes file. Instead you annotate a controller method with what restful endpoint you want it to be. Doesn't matter if it's ajax or not. And if you have more than one http verb (ie. two POSTs) in a controller then you can easily say that one controller method requires a query param different than the other method. Easy peasy.

Comment: Nice bro, i appreciate yout for sharing your ideas with me.

Comment: No prob! So in summary, nowadays I don't have to worry about if I return html or JSON (don't care how you hit endpoint, whether via ajax or not, you'll get JSON), since now I always return JSON (because backend = API). Naturally goes well with front-end Single-Page-Apps (check out VueJS 2.0 or ReactJS). Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can't make this dispatch in the routing layer if you keep the same URL. You have two options :

1. Use different routes for your AJAX calls. For example, you can prefix all your ajax calls by `/api`. This is a common way :

   ```
   Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
   {

       Route::get('items', function()
       {
           //
       });

   });
   ```
2. If the only different thing is your response format. You can use a condition in your controller. Laravel provides methods for that, for example :

   ```
   public function index()
   {
       $items = ...;

       if (Request::ajax()) {
           return Response::json($items);
       } else {
           return View::make('items.index');
       }
   }
   ```

You can read this http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ajax and this http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-groups if you want more details.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, thanks for your suggestions. I think that #1 would already increase a growing routes file, when I would rather keep it one-line (but still give good readable route intent to other developers). And #2 is going to fill up the top of my `index` method with a big switch-like set of calls to other methods. I'll also have to type this up each time (not as DRY as I like).

Comment: But you are correct it in seems the Framework doesn't have a natural way to support this. However, I was able to plug into some methods using **middleware** (see my answer).

Comment: If you are using L5, do not worry about tons of routes it does not decrease performance because you can cache routes. FREE demo: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/8

Comment: +1 @Kyslik, but there is still the issue of readability with all that being in one file. In Laravel 4.1 I used to do `Route::any('some/page/',      array('as' => 'some-page','uses' => (Request::ajax() ? 'SomePageController@ajax' : 'SomePageController@index')));` and do like Alexandre mentioned by having all the if/then conditions in a method `public function ajax()` in my controller. It's probably my preference, but I just think Http controllers should represent all the request action that's going on a page. Services/etc can be reused, but I like all requests for a page showing together.

Comment: Keeps a website still a "website" until you need it to be an API.

Comment: In that case I would create new file and include it on bottom of routes I am not sure if it works just like that but thats how I would approach "too many routes". I am sure that middleware can do that for you send request to wherever needed. Try dig in middleware documentation I think it will make some sense. Oh, you already answered here with middleware in mind.

Comment: Yeah, I already came up with a solution (see my answer) that uses middleware. I'm guess I'm now waiting it out, see what else folks can come up with.

Comment: I also saw Taylor respond here to a solution using the parent controller: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1280

Comment: Also, as another example, it's nice to keep the CRUD requests all together. (Since the verbs, resourceful controllers, don't always work in every browser, or at least there is a debate going on). I think the standard approach has been to add `hidden` inputs that post the http verb. Plus, many times you just have more request action variations.